# Website on S3: Multiple subdomains to one Bucket?

Tags: dns, 301-redirect, amazon-s3, no-www

I'd like to host a website on **Amazon S3**. What's the best practice to make a site accessible from both `example.com` and `www.example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

You should choose one version to use and 301 redirect from one to the other. I don't know if you can use a htaccess file on S3 but if not you may be able to do the redirect from you domain name's control panel.

Comment: No, .htaccess can't be used with S3 (that's an Apache specific file). Since S3 can't host naked domains, only subdomains because it uses a CNAME record, you would host www.example.com in the bucket and redirect example.com to the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon offers a free micro server for one year. http://aws.amazon.com/free/ you may be better off setting up a public AMI LAMP stack and have the freedom to configure your website however you'd like.